# Fixed 3D plot title in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, title, fixed

I wanted to included a title into my 3D plot in Matlab, but the problem I'm facing right now is that if I rotate the plot, the title also moves. Does anyone know how to fix its location no matter how much you rotate your plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can add a textbox at the top and make it's background color the same as the figure (normally gray; [0.8 0.8 0.8]). Try out the following:

```
close all
clc
clear

[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);

figure;
surf(X,Y,Z);

%// Use uicontrol to place a fixed text box.
uicontrol('Style','text','Position', [200 400 200 20],'String','Super fixed title!','FontSize',16,'HorizontalAlignment','Center','BackgroundColor',[.8 .8 .8])

rotate3d on
```

It looks like this and it does not move!

[image]

Note that if you resize the figure it will move around. To fix this you need to use normalized units in the definition of the figure:

```
figure('Units','normalized');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: great then glad to help! :)